# Sending values to OAuth - Header or querystring?

Tags: asp.net, oauth

When requesting authorization (or whatever other type of request), should the parameters `oauth_token`and `oauth_signature`  be sent **via querystring or** by adding them as values in your **HttpWebRequest.Header** as a `NameValueCollection` additions to the header?

Comment: It depends on the server implementation, the oauth spec supports both. What api are you working with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on their example ruby code they are looking for it in the header.

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
        "API_CONSUMER_KEY",
        "API_CONSUMER_SECRET",
        :site => "https://yoursite.Desk.com",
        :scheme => :header
)
```

The oauth_token and oauth_signature (along with all of the other params that start with oauth_) would all go in the authorization http header as comma seperated name value pairs as shown here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.5.1

Here's a quick example using the [DevDefined.OAuth library](https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth)...

```
var endPoint = new Uri("https://yoursite.Desk.com");
var ctx = new OAuthConsumerContext
{
    ConsumerKey = "consumerkey1",
    ConsumerSecret = "consumersecret1",
    SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1
};

var session = new OAuthSession(ctx, endPoint);
session.AccessToken = new TokenBase
{
    Token = "ACCESS_TOKEN",
    TokenSecret = "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCRET"
};

var respText = session.Request().Get().ForUri(endPoint).ToString();
```

Comment: I just talked with one of their support guys.  He's saying it can be in the header OR querystring....I guess from what he's saying.

Comment: fyi, you should be refing this http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849#ref-W3C.REC-html40-19980424 instead..the link you're looking at for OAuth is outdated.

Comment: another thing I don't get is the signature.  For requesting temporary credentials to requesting an access token, there's this signature that's being passed via HmacSha1 but there's no info on what this signature consists of or how it is to be formed (what fields, etc.).  I'm referring to the OAuth documentation, for instance oauth_signature="74KNZJeDHnMBp0EMJ9ZHt%2FXKycU%3D"

Comment: That is why I linked you to a 3rd party .net library because getting the signature and everything else right can be tricky. Section 3.4 of rfc5849 talks about creating the signature. You basically need to collect all of your oauth parameters, and query string parameters sort and encode them to create your base string. You then hmac sign it using SHARED_SECRET&TOKEN_SECRET as your key. If you want to implement it yourself, this is a pretty good starting point http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs